# Level curve and a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to make the following picture using tikz[image]

Surface is easy to draw but the level curve is difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I feel you'd be better off if you try to build on other posts, including answers that you got.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=7cm,height=11cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,ymin=0,xmin=0,zmin=0,smooth,
    colormap/hot,view={115}{20},
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
    declare function={f(\x)=15+\x*\x;k=3;}]
  \draw[blue] plot[variable=\y,domain=0:360,smooth cycle]
  ({7+k*cos(\y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*\y)-0.2*cos(\y))},{7+k*sin(\y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*\y)-0.2*cos(\y))},{0});
  \fill[blue,fill opacity=0.5] plot[variable=\y,domain=290:97]
  ({7+k*cos(\y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*\y)-0.2*cos(\y))},{7+k*sin(\y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*\y)-0.2*cos(\y))},{f(k)})  
  -- (7,12.5,{f(k)}) -- (1.5,12.5,{f(k)}) -- (1.5,1.5,{f(k)}) -- (7,1.5,{f(k)}) -- cycle;
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain y=0:360,samples y=51,domain=0:4,z buffer=sort] 
   ({7+x*cos(y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*y)-0.2*cos(y))},{7+x*sin(y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*y)-0.2*cos(y))},{f(x)});
  \fill[blue,fill opacity=0.5] plot[variable=\y,domain=-70:97]
  ({7+k*cos(\y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*\y)-0.2*cos(\y))},{7+k*sin(\y)*(1-0.2*cos(2*\y)-0.2*cos(\y))},{f(k)})  
  -- (7,12.5,{f(k)}) -- (12.5,12.5,{f(k)}) -- (12.5,1.5,{f(k)}) -- (7,1.5,{f(k)}) -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]